# How to write the .htaccess file to generate friendly URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

Talking about converting ugly URLs to friendly URLs with the .htaccess file:

Do you know how to convert this?

```
http://www.domainname.com.co/index.php?tpl=contenido&categoria=noticias-afic&id=35&alias=article-title
```

... into this?

```
http://www.domainname.com.co/contenido/noticias-afic/35/article-title
```

The URL changes dynamically.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?tpl=$1&categoria=$2&id=$3&alias=$4 [L]
```

It should allow you to access http://www.domainname.com.co/index.php?tpl=contenido&categoria=noticias-afic&id=35&alias=article-title using http://www.domainname.com.co/contenido/noticias-afic/35/article-title